# How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to add data in firebase database using webpage.
For unique id I want to use date and time like below format
MTB + yyyyddmmhhmmss
MTB20190517083578

How to do this? Please tell me any one.

Comment: What happens if two records are added in the same second? Not so "unique" now...

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) wich handles a lot of weird Date behaviours (like non UTC dates and formatting).

If you use moment you can format the date using:

```
moment().format('MTBYYYYMMDDhhmmss')
```